# Kotlin Android Studio - TextInputLayout in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-appcompat, layout-inflater

I need to inflate a custom layout to an AlertDialog.

This is my code:

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
        val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_autocancel, autocancel_root) //Inflate layout for AlertDialog

        val alertDialogHour = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle) //build AlertDialog

        alertDialogHour.setView(dialogView) //set inflated layout
```

Everything works fine, but when I add to my custom layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#d37a7a"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/minute_editText"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#d37a7a"
            android:hint="@string/minute"
            android:fontFamily="@font/product_sans_regular"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

It gives me the error

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class 
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class

I know that TextInputLayout require an AppCompat theme, so I was thinking to use `LayoutInflaterCompat`, but the documentation is pretty a mess, and there's no online guide. 
What can I do?

EDIT

This is my build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

}

Comment: Have you added material component dependecies? Can you put your build.gradle (App) level dependecy

Comment: I have 2 more TextInputLayout in my main layout and they works fine. Anyway, I edited question with my dependencies

Comment: Try removing backgroundTint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not inflate View by yourself. `AlertDialog.Builder` have `setView(res:Int)` function that inflate layout itself.

**Sample:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(R.layout.alertdialog_autocancel)
            .create()
```

Comment: If I let the Builder inflate the layout itself I can't get input values later in onClick() of the buttons because I don't know on which view I should call findViewById(input). I have no problem with inflating a view.  AlertDialog.Builder has setView(View view) that works without any problem for me.